# Pivoting a Pandas dataframe with a gapless daterange as index

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

**Question:** With the title as condition, how do I achieve the desired result displayed below?

**Sample Data:**

```
     Date       Client      Order
0    1/30/1987  AAA         O.N. 111
1    3/28/1987  BBB         O.N. 112
2    3/28/1987  CCC         O.N. 113
3    3/28/1987  AAA         O.N. 114
4    3/31/1987  DDD         O.N. 115
5    3/31/1987  BBB         O.N. 116
6    3/31/1987  EEE         O.N. 117
7    4/1/1987   FFF         O.N. 118
8    4/1/1987   CCC         O.N. 119
9    4/1/1987   AAA         O.N. 120
10   4/2/1987   DDD         O.N. 121
```

**Desired Result:**

```
            AAA BBB CCC DDD EEE FFF
1987-01-30  111 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1987-01-31  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1987-02-01  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
...
1987-03-28  114 112 113 NaN NaN NaN
...
1987-03-31  NaN 116 NaN 115 117 NaN
1987-04-01  120 NaN 119 NaN NaN 118
1987-04-02  NaN NaN NaN 121 NaN NaN
```

**Approaches tried:**

```
# Results to an error.
df_p = df.pivot(index='Date',columns='Client',values='Order')

# Almost there, but I don't want to iterate over each cell to get Order number.
df_symbol = df['Client']
df_symbol_unique = set(df_symbol)
index = pd.date_range(df['Date'].iat[0],df['Date'].iat[-1])
df_new = pd.DataFrame(np.NaN,index=index,columns=sorted(list(df_symbol_unique)))

#               AAA BBB CCC DDD EEE FFF
#1987-01-30     NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
#1987-01-31     NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
#1987-02-01     NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
#...
```

**Related links checked (that doesn't seem to address issue):**

1. [concat pandas DataFrame along timeseries indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11714768/concat-pandas-dataframe-along-timeseries-indexes)
2. [transpose multiple columns Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25852504/transpose-multiple-columns-pandas-dataframe)

**Notes:**

1. `Date` column is always sorted from oldest to newest.
2. A Client will never have more than 1 order/day.
3. There has to be no gaps in the date range, hence the `index` given above.

**Update:**

Apparently, there are indeed repeating client-order pairs on later dates, contrary to Note 2 above, which is what's messing my data (so much for checking only 20,000 rows in a million, pfft) and the pivot. DSM's answer (and my initial hunch) is correct that pivot is the solution.

Given this, I'm thinking, is there a possible way to use the *count* instead of orders for each client, rather than get the order number themselves?

**Update 2:**

Piggybacking on DSM's answer but using `pivot_table` instead.

```
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
df_p = df.pivot_table(rows="Date", cols="Client", values="Order", aggfunc=len)
df_p = df_p.reindex(pd.date_range(df_p.index.min(), df_p.index.max()))
```

Gives the following output on a modified table:

```
Client      AAA  BBB  CCC  DDD  EEE  FFF
1987-01-30    1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1987-01-31  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1987-02-01  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1987-02-02  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1987-02-03  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN

[5 rows x 6 columns]
Client      AAA  BBB  CCC  DDD  EEE  FFF
1987-03-29  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1987-03-30  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1987-03-31  NaN    1  NaN    1    1  NaN
1987-04-01    2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    1
1987-04-02  NaN  NaN  NaN    1  NaN  NaN

[5 rows x 6 columns]
[Finished in 1.4s]
```

Good enough for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this -- which looks pretty similar to what you tried, to be honest -- works for me:

```
>>> df
         Date Client     Order
0   1/30/1987    AAA  O.N. 111
1   3/28/1987    BBB  O.N. 112
2   3/28/1987    CCC  O.N. 113
3   3/28/1987    AAA  O.N. 114
4   3/31/1987    DDD  O.N. 115
5   3/31/1987    BBB  O.N. 116
6   3/31/1987    EEE  O.N. 117
7    4/1/1987    FFF  O.N. 118
8    4/1/1987    CCC  O.N. 119
9    4/1/1987    AAA  O.N. 120
10   4/2/1987    DDD  O.N. 121
>>> df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
>>> df["Order"] = df["Order"].str.split().str[-1]
>>> df_p = df.pivot(index="Date", columns="Client", values="Order")
>>> df_p = df_p.reindex(pd.date_range(df_p.index.min(), df_p.index.max()))
```

which gives:

```
>>> df_p.head()
Client      AAA  BBB  CCC  DDD  EEE  FFF
1987-01-30  111  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1987-01-31  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1987-02-01  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1987-02-02  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1987-02-03  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
>>> df_p.tail()
Client      AAA  BBB  CCC  DDD  EEE  FFF
1987-03-29  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1987-03-30  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1987-03-31  NaN  116  NaN  115  117  NaN
1987-04-01  120  NaN  119  NaN  NaN  118
1987-04-02  NaN  NaN  NaN  121  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Looks awesome, but I get a `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape` error, which is not supposed to happen AFAIK. Any ideas as to what might cause said error? :/

Comment: Even with that 11-row sample?  What version of `pandas` are you using?

Comment: Yes, even with that. Also, in the data, I've only personally checked about 20,000 rows out of a million, but I'm pretty sure there are no dates with more than one order per client. Pandas version is 0.13.1.

Comment: Hmm.  What is `df.index[0]`?  The only way I can reproduce that error is if your index isn't really what it looks like it is (e.g. it's really a multiindex, and so df.index[0] is a tuple.)

Comment: `df.index[0]` is `0`. Weird. This is just your normal, every day CSV export from a database. :/ I'll try playing around and let you know if it hits anything from other columns.

Comment: Also, +1, since I don't doubt it works for you. I'll check my data. Possibly overlooking something trivial here.

Comment: @Nanashi: I'd try two things just to rule out the obvious possibilities -- try [this code](http://dpaste.com/300R20X) just to make sure we're working with exactly the same frame, and upgrade pandas to make sure there's no bug you've hit (I don't have a pure 0.13.1 around to test with.)

Comment: Oh, wow. Yours actually works. FML, this is going to be a long day checking the data. :<

Comment: Confirmed it: somewhere in the much later dates, there are days wherein the Client has two different Orders in the same date, which is what's causing the duplicate error. Since this seems to be my problem, I'm accepting your answer. I'll find a way to use the count of orders instead of the order number. Thanks, DSM!